# edit boxes inside details tag in html

Tags: html

[image]I have 3 edit boxes inside `<details>` tag. When I click on "Add User", I get the form. My query is on how to maintain the space between two edit boxes. If I dont keep these within the details tag, it works fine. Given below is the code.

```html
<details>
  <summary>Add User</summary>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="Name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="MobNum">Mobile No.</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MobNum">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="EmailID">Email ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailID">
    </div>
  </div>
</details>
```

With the `details` tag, edit boxes seems to be overlapped.

**Expected:**

[image]

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant CSS - looks like bootstrap or somthing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```css
.form-group { padding: 10px; width:300px; }
.form-control { float:right; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<details>
  <summary>Add User</summary>

  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="MobNum">Mobile No.</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MobNum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="EmailID">Email ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailID">
  </div>
</details>
```

Or this?

```css
.form-group { padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px; width:350px; float:left }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<details>
  <summary>Add User</summary>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
  </div><wbr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="MobNum">Mobile No.</label>&nbsp;<input type="number" class="form-control" id="MobNum">
  </div><wbr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="EmailID">Email ID</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailID">
  </div>
</details><hr style="clear:left" />
<details>
  <summary>Modify user</summary>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
  </div><wbr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="MobNum">Mobile No.</label>&nbsp;<input type="number" class="form-control" id="MobNum">
  </div><wbr/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="EmailID">Email ID</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailID">
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isnt solving my issue. I want all those edit boxes in single line with space. In my case its overlapping.

Comment: If I just remove `<div class="form-row">` in my code, its works fine. I want it on a single line and not on next line.

Comment: That was completely unclear that you meant horizontal space, since the snippet I made you show them vertical- can you show a picture of what you want?

Comment: Added the screenshot in the question. If you see the boxes are overlapped. Apologise for not giving screenshot earlier.

Comment: Please see update - you need to have a wide enough screen for the effect

Comment: Not working as expected. Sharing the expected screen as well.

Comment: You have to give more information- what is expected behaviour and why does my suggestion not work as expected? There is no overlap

Comment: Sorry but when I implemented your suggestion, the exit boxes are coming in two different rows. I want it in a single row. Should I try decreasing the width or any other parameters? You mentioned like wide enough screen right?

Comment: I was making error in adding the `.form-group`. Your reply has solved my answer. So accepting your answer. I have a small query on this. If I have to add another `<detail>`. How can I do that. Meaning I have Add user expand and collapse. Next Line I want to add `Modify User`. In case if I directly add it, that `Modify User` will also change its position based on expansion of `Add user`. Got my query?

Comment: What I meant was that the boxes WILL drop to the next line when the screen is narrower than there is room for 3 boxes.

Comment: I added a Modify user

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the details.